# Number Theory Squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, algebraic-number-theory

Determine all natural numbers $n ≥ 2$ for which
$$n=a^2+b^2$$
holds, where *a* is the smallest divisor of *n* other than 1 and *b* is any divisor of *n*.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you found a single example?

Comment: Does $8=2^2+2^2$ count, or do you need $b \neq a$ ?

Comment: $20=2^2+4^2$ is an example where $a \neq b.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We obviosly have $a$ is prime. Since $a\mid n = a^2+b^2$, we have $a\mid b$, so $b = a k$.

But $b \mid n = a^2+b^2$, so $b \mid a^2$. Then $a k \mid a^2$, so $k \mid a$. Since $a$ is prime, $k=1$ or $k=a$.

If $k=1$ we have $b=a$, then $n=2a^2$, but since $a$ is the smaller non-trivial divisor, $a=2$, so $n=8$.

If $k=a$ we have $b=a^2$, then $n=a^2+a^4=a^2(1+a^2)$ that is even, so again $a=2$ and $n = 2^2+ 4^2 = 20$.

So the only solutions are $n = 8, 20$.

Answer (score 2):

$a,b$ and $n$ cannot all be odd and so, in all cases, $n$ is even and $a=2$. Then $$n=4+b^2.$$
Since $b$ is a factor of $n$ it is a factor of $4$ and so $b=1,2\text { or }4$.

The solutions are $a=2$ and $n=8\text{ or }20$.

Comment: "$a$,$b$ and $n$ cannot all be odd and so, in all cases, $n$ is even ..."
What about the case where $n$ and $a$ are odd and $b$ is even?

Comment: b is a divisor of n so how can n be odd and b even!!

Comment: Yes, i know, but by the wording of your answer, you seems to conclude that $n$ is even only by parity considerations, there's no mention of the hypothesis.

Comment: Your assumption as to my thoughts are completely wrong.

Comment: I'm not assuming nothing about your thoughts, i´m reading what you wrote.